# How to convert character codes from UTF-8 to Shift JIS in scala spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to convert character codes from UTF-8 to Shift-JIS in `data.txt` file.

What should I do?

This is my code, but it's not correct.

It suffers from problems like below.

1. Do not run on spark environment.
   error:
   java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException when acessing list of lists
2. the result output is the file with the character encoding is ANSI, not Shift-jis.

```
    import scala.io.Source 
    import scala.io._ 
    import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer 
    import scala.collection.mutable 
    import java.io.BufferedReader 
    import java.io.BufferedWriter 
    import java.io.File 
    import java.io.FileInputStream 
    import java.io.FileOutputStream 
    import java.io.InputStreamReader 
    import java.io.OutputStreamWriter 
    import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._ 
    import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD 
    import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession 

    object uconv { 
      def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = { 
        val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("Spark_Accumulator").getOrCreate() 
        val fis: FileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File("data.txt")) 
        val in: BufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis, "UTF8")) 
        val fos: FileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File("output.txt")) 
        val out: BufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos, "SJIS")) 
        val len: Int = 80 
        val buf: Array[Char] = Array.ofDim[Char](len) 
        var numRead: Int = 0 
        while ((numRead = in.read(buf, 0, len)) != -1) 
        out.write(buf, 0, numRead) 
        out.close() 
        in.close() 
      } 
    }
```

Please correct the code to help me properly.

Comment: It would be great if you can mention which part you think is not correct in your code

Comment: I don't see how your task relates to Apache Spark. If you only need to translate a file from UTF-8 to Shift-JIS, you can simply use `iconv` (if running macOS, *BSD, or Linux): `iconv -f UTF-8 -t SHIFT_JISX0213 data.txt > output.txt`.

Comment: @ammportal I have updated the question. Hope you confirm it

Comment: @HristoIliev I know that statement. But now I want it to run on spark environment